# Unable to catch Mysql2::Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently testing the following code:

```
def db_check
  begin 
    schema_call = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      :adapter => 'mysql2',
      :host => 'localhost',
      :database => 'dev_db',
      :username => 'dev_user',
      :password => 'dev_pw').connection.execute("SELECT * FROM schema_migrations LIMIT 1")

    if schema_call
      render :status => 200, :file => "public/success.html"
    else
      render :status => 500, :file => "public/query_fail.html"
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "#{e.class} ;; #{e.message}"
    logger.debug "#{e.class}"
    render :status => 500, :file => "public/500.html"
  end
end
```

The eventual goal is to have a call to a MySQL server to see if 1) the server is still up and 2) if the database is available. If the connection doesn't work, an **Error** is thrown, so I put the code in a `rescue` block. Unfortunately, even when I use `rescue Exception`, which I understand to be advised against, I still get a **Mysql2::Error** message in the browser (I also tried rescue `Mysql2:Error`, which had no effect).

The duplication of error logging in the `rescue` is extra attempts to get additional information to work with, but nothing has worked so far. Anyone know how to catch this error?

UPDATE: also, for additional context, testing the code with MySQL not running currently (condition if the DB server is down), get back the following:

```
Mysql2::Error
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

which makes partial sense, given the server is off, but I still don't understand why it isn't rescuing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `rescue` isn't catching the **Mysql2::Error** is that the error isn't coming from the **ActiveRecord::Base** code, but rather is Rails throwing an error because it can't connect to the MySQL server that it expects (which I had turned off to test the above code).

Comment: Seriously - there has to be some way to rescue this.

Comment: @TJ Biddle: IanL's `begin rescue` example does work in capturing my `MySQL2::Error ... foreign key constraint fails`. I am verifying that a foreign key constraint exists on the database side using rspec which now works. Thank you IanL.